# MySQL union sorting select statements separately instead of combining

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, union-all

My query works and is giving me correct results -- but it's ordering the two selects result sets separately and then concatenating the second result set to the end of the first and I don't know why! I want both sets to be ordered together.

```sql
(SELECT 
    m.m_name AS 'Merchant',
    log.ship_day AS 'Date',
    log.num_orders AS '# Orders',
    'Sales Exec' AS 'Dept',
    CONCAT(ciii.i_fname, ' ', ciii.i_lname) AS 'Rep',
    log.m_sales_executive_days AS 'Days',
    CONCAT(log.m_sales_executive_level,
            ' (',
            log.m_sales_executive_com,
            '*',
            log.num_orders,
            ')') AS 'Level',
    log.m_sales_executive_payout AS 'Payout'
FROM
    commissions.commissions_log AS log
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.merchants m ON m.m_id = log.m_id
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.users uuu ON uuu.u_id = log.m_sales_executive
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.contact_info ciii ON uuu.u_i_id = ciii.i_id
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.users uuuu ON uuuu.u_id = log.m_account_manager
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.contact_info ciiii ON uuuu.u_i_id = ciiii.i_id) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT 
    m.m_name AS 'Merchant',
    log.ship_day AS 'Date',
    log.num_orders AS '# Orders',
    'Account Exec' AS 'Dept',
    CONCAT(ciiii.i_fname, ' ', ciiii.i_lname) AS 'Rep',
    log.m_account_manager_days AS 'Days',
    CONCAT(log.m_account_manager_level,
            ' (',
            log.m_account_manager_com,
            '*',
            log.num_orders,
            ')') AS 'Level',
    log.m_account_manager_payout AS 'Payout'
FROM
    commissions.commissions_log AS log
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.merchants m ON m.m_id = log.m_id
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.users uuu ON uuu.u_id = log.m_sales_executive
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.contact_info ciii ON uuu.u_i_id = ciii.i_id
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.users uuuu ON uuuu.u_id = log.m_account_manager
        LEFT JOIN
    acf_rds_new.contact_info ciiii ON uuuu.u_i_id = ciiii.i_id) 

ORDER BY 'Date' ASC , 'Merchant' ASC , '# Orders' DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire result-set to be `order`ed, you should have another `select` statement.

```
select * from
(your query with union all) t
order by 'Date' ASC , 'Merchant' ASC , '# Orders' DESC
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem the original query did; it is sorting by string values, rather than field names. The simple answer by Gordon pinpoints the issue exactly.

Answer (score 2):

It you want the two subqueries to be ordered, then don't use constants in your `order by` statement.  The proper escape character is backtick, but you only need that for that last columns:

```
ORDER BY Date ASC , Merchant ASC , `# Orders` DESC
```

As a general rule, do not use single quotes for column names.  *Only* use single quotes for string and date constants.  Otherwise, you are prone to make errors, such as the one in your query.

Comment: This was just as helpful as the answer I went with (went with @vkp because he was first)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```